# Error on mac when compiling certain packages in R - fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory

Tags: r, compiler-errors, r-package

I am working in RStudio and having problems installing from sources an R package that contains C++ code. I have followed instructions from several websites about installing Xcode and gcc, changing my `~/.R/Makevars` file, etc., to be able to compile C++ code. I now see fewer error messages, but this one persists:

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.1.0_1/include/c++/11.1.0/cmath:45,
                 from /Users/nickjacob/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100,
                 from /Users/nickjacob/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62,
                 from /Users/nickjacob/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30,
                 from /Users/nickjacob/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo/interface/RcppArmadilloForward.h:25,
                 from /Users/nickjacob/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:29,
                 from helloworld.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.1.0_1/lib/gcc/11/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/11.1.0/include-fixed/math.h:45:10: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what to do. Any suggestions?

---

My `~/.R/Makevars` file looks like this:

```makefile
CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++
FC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
F77=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
PKG_LIBS = -fopenmp -lgomp
PKG_CFLAGS= -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp
PKG_CXXFLAGS=-fopenmp -std=c++11
CFLAGS= -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FCFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS = -fopenmp
# change the next line according to your computer compiler version (use gcc -v in terminal):
FLIBS=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
CFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
CXXFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion"
```

Comment: You appear to be using a compiler from Homebrew.  Are you doing all your installs (including the install of R) from Homebrew, or just this one?  Generally the compiler for packages should match the one used for R, unless you really know what you're doing.  Follow the instructions at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html if you're using R from CRAN.

Comment: I use homebrew to install everything, however I don't actually remember whether I used Homebrew or CRAN to install R. Is there a quick way to check? I believe R was installed on my mac with homebrew, but not 100% sure.

Comment: This command `R CMD config CC` prints this:
`clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13` with the CRAN build.  Probably not with yours.  So I'd suggest using a CRAN build, but it'll be a lot of work.

Comment: Yeah the output for me reads: /usr/local/bin/gcc              When you say it will be a lot of work, that's because I'll have to reinstall all packages etc?

Comment: Reinstall R and all packages, yes.